# What is my mistake in deploying Next Js App?

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

I have an error when I deploy the project in Vercel.

My Error

```
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...

Failed to compile.
./components/Footer.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'next/Image' in '/vercel/path0/components'

Import trace for requested module:
./components/Layout.js
./pages/_app.js
> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

But in footer I write `import Image from "next/Image";`

My footer

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/Image";
import Logo from "../public/images/Logo.svg";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import EnvelopeIcon from "../public/images/envelope.svg";
import PhoneIcon from "../public/images/phone.svg";
import MapChecker from "../public/images/map-marker-check.svg";

const Footer = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <footer>
      <div className="footer-context container">
        <div className="footer-navbar">
          <div className="logo">
            <Link href={"/"}>
              <Image src={Logo} alt="GlobalSoft logo" />
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="line"></div>
        <div className="footer-info">
          <div className="card envelope">
            <a href="mailto:info@globalsoft.az">
              <div className="card-image">
                <Image src={EnvelopeIcon} alt="Envelope Icon" />{" "}
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="card phone">
            <a href="tel:+994 99 894 45 05 ">
              <div className="card-image">
                <Image src={PhoneIcon} alt="Phone Icon" />{" "}
              </div>
       
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="card address">
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://goo.gl/maps/FzvbQnQEtpZCPKLm8">
              <div className="card-image">
                <Image src={MapChecker} alt="Map Check Icon" />{" "}
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Comment: Next.js `Image` component must be imported from `next/image` not `next/Image`.

Answer (score 0):

The Image component **requires** width and weight to be specified.